# Help identifying 27" 2012 iMac internal plugs

Tags: wiring

I'm going to convert an old iMac into a 5k monitor, but I'd like to identify some plugs so I can have cables made rather than solder. I'm going to see if the cost (after prototype) is reasonable to order a bunch and offer a kit for sale. I apologize in advance for my ignorance of terminology.

For the power switch, it's 1mm OD tall and a bit over 2 mm(2.5mm?) OD wide. [image: Power switch 1] [image: Power switch 2]

For the power supply, it's made of three "barrels" or pins that are 2mm x 2mm OD. [image: Power supply 1] [image: Power supply 2]

And internal speakers are 1mm OD x 9mm OD with room for six pins. [image: Speaker connector 1] [image: Speaker Connector 2] [image: Speaker connector 3]

If anyone can help with any of this, that would be fantastic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked for the schematic? They float around online and tend to be very detailed

Comment: Power supply looks like Molex.

Comment: @MadHatter You’re correct. Thanks! I ordered from Amazon and confirmed. The hunt for the others continues.

Answer (score 0):

The 2012 iMac had a 2560x1440 display, not the later 5120x2880 (5k) version introduced in 2014.

These earlier ones could directly be used as a monitor with no modifications for some uses.

[Using an iMac as a monitor](https://www.lifewire.com/use-imac-as-monitor-with-target-display-mode-2260906)

Comment: The case and speakers I’m using are from a 2012. The display panel is a 2015 5k panel. I’ve been able  to test functionality, but if i can ID these items, I’d like to try putting together a solderless kit.